# callback to handle completion of pipe

Tags: node.js

I am using the following node.js code to download documents from some url and save it in the disk.
I want to be informed about when the document is downloaded. i have not seen any callback with pipe.Or, Is there any 'end' event that can be captured on completion of download ?

```
request(some_url_doc).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('xyz.doc'));
```

Answer (score 333, accepted):

Streams are `EventEmitter`s so you can listen to certain events. As you said there is a `finish` event for request (previously `end`).

```
 var stream = request(...).pipe(...);
 stream.on('finish', function () { ... });
```

For more information about which events are available you can check the [stream documentation page](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish).

Comment: `var r = request(...).on("end",function(){/* CALLBACK */}).pipe(...);`

Comment: for me the event 'close', rather than 'end' works `r.on('close'), function () {...})`

Comment: The 'end' event is now 'finish'
Pipe events: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Comment: The 'end' event still exists and is used on Readable streams. Writable streams use 'finish'. This is because the Transform stream is a mix of both and needs to differentiate between the events.

Comment: I've tried this but only the `'complete'` event worked.

Comment: This thread is a good summary of how working with node streams looks like.

Comment: @Pickels this answer looks cool, but have a Q: the "var stream" is the source stream or dest stream, the one you request from or pipe into ?

Comment: Does `finish` fire in case of `error`, or should I add a separate callback to handle interruptions?

Answer (score 45):

Based nodejs document, http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish,
it should handle writableStream's `finish` event.

```
var writable = getWriteable();
var readable = getReadable();
readable.pipe(writable);
writable.on('finish', function(){ ... });
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for me with node v0.12.7, but your solution does.

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76262508/node-js-writable-finish-not-emitted-after-pushing-null-into-pipe

Answer (score 9):

Code snippet for piping content from web via http(s) to filesystem. As  @starbeamrainbowlabs noticed event `finish` does job

```
var tmpFile = "/tmp/somefilename.doc";

var ws = fs.createWriteStream(tmpFile);
ws.on('finish', function() {
  // pipe done here, do something with file
});

var client = url.slice(0, 5) === 'https' ? https : http;
client.get(url, function(response) {
  return response.pipe(ws);
});
```

Comment: The on 'finish' works for me and 'end' does not. Thank you!

Comment: in one particular case, finish seems to be firing before all the expected bytes arrive

Answer (score 5):

I found an a bit different solution of my problem regarding this context. Thought worth sharing.

Most of the example create `readStreams` from file. But in my case `readStream` has to be created from `JSON` string coming from a message pool.

```
var jsonStream = through2.obj(function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
                    this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk, null, 4) + '\n');
                    callback();
                });
// message.value --> value/text to write in write.txt 
jsonStream.write(JSON.parse(message.value));
var writeStream = sftp.createWriteStream("/path/to/write/write.txt");

//"close" event didn't work for me!
writeStream.on( 'close', function () {
    console.log( "- done!" );
    sftp.end();
    }
);

//"finish" event didn't work for me either!
writeStream.on( 'close', function () {
    console.log( "- done!"
        sftp.end();
        }
);

// finally this worked for me!
jsonStream.on('data', function(data) {
    var toString = Object.prototype.toString.call(data);
    console.log('type of data:', toString);
    console.log( "- file transferred" );
});

jsonStream.pipe( writeStream );
```

Comment: Instead of listening for "finish" you have two handlers for "close", maybe that was the reason. The "finish" event works for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that handles errors in requests and calls a callback after the file is written:

```
request(opts)
    .on('error', function(err){ return callback(err)})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
    .on('finish', function (err) {
        return callback(err);
    });
```