# Gulp.src doesn't emit any file

Tags: gulp, task

I've got this gulp file

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css')
const rimraf = require('rimraf')
const concat = require('gulp-concat')

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    rimraf('./dist/*', cb)
})

gulp.task('sass', function(cb) {
    gulp.src('./src/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    console.log('before')
    cb(undefined)
})

gulp.task('minify', function(cb) {
    gulp.src('./src/**/*.css')
      .pipe(cleanCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    console.log('before')
    cb(undefined)
})

gulp.task('build:css', ['sass', 'minify'], function() {
    gulp.src('./dist/**/*.css')
      .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    console.log('after')
})

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start('build:css')
})

gulp.task('build:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.scss', ['build'])
})
```

But when I run `build:watch`

```
[11:26:18] Using gulpfile C:\dev\web\ikea_design\gulpfile.js
[11:26:18] Starting 'build:watch'...
[11:26:18] Finished 'build:watch' after 16 ms
[11:26:24] Starting 'clean'...
[11:26:24] Finished 'clean' after 11 ms
[11:26:24] Starting 'build'...
[11:26:24] Starting 'sass'...
before
[11:26:24] Finished 'sass' after 12 ms
[11:26:24] Starting 'minify'...
before
[11:26:24] Finished 'minify' after 2.27 ms
[11:26:24] Starting 'build:css'...
after
[11:26:24] Finished 'build:css' after 1.16 ms
[11:26:24] Finished 'build' after 25 ms
```

even if it displays the two *before*s before the *after*, `style.css.min` doesn't get created. That's strange since the css files should have already been saved in the `dist` folder by the time `concat` gets invoked. 
What's wrong?

### Edit

I've run gulp-debug inside of `build:css` and it shows 0 items in the pipe

Comment: Don't think it's related but you are running the minify task on the wrong folder: `gulp.src('./src/**/*.css')`, shouldn't it be `gulp.src('./dist/**/*.css')`?

Comment: No, that's ok, because my `src` folder contains either `.sass` and `.css` files, and whilst the formers are compressed by `gulp-sass`, the ladders have to be minified somehow. And then, when everything is minified, I want to concatenate it

Comment: I found the solution at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619290/making-gulp-write-files-synchronously-before-moving-on-to-the-next-task). Since file writing is asynchronous, I've to make sure that it happens synchronously instead.