# Detecting the end of a piped stream operation

Tags: node.js

I am having an issue with detecting end of piped stream.
steps:

1. Read File
2. Creating gzip
3. Write File

Which is the right way to detect **end of** piped stream read and write.

```
var inp = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
var out = fs.createWriteStream(fileName + '.gz');
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
out.on('finish', function () { ....
```

vs

```
var inp = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
var out = fs.createWriteStream(fileName + '.gz');
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
var zipStream = inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
zipStream.on('finish', function () { ....
```

[reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447872/callback-to-handle-completion-of-pipe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html:

- `'finish'`: is emitted after the stream.end() method has been called, and all data has been flushed to the underlying system.
- `'end'`: is emitted when there is no more data to be consumed from the stream.

> ### Events: 'finish' and 'end'
>
> The '`finish`' and '`end`' events are from the `stream.Writable` and
>   `stream.Readable` classes, respectively. The `'finish'` event is emitted
>   after `stream.end()` is called and all chunks have been processed by
>   `stream._transform()`. The '`end`' event is emitted after all data has
>   been output, which occurs after the callback in `transform._flush()` has
>   been called.

So, in your example, the order will be:

- `inp` (readable stream) will emit the '`end`'
- `gzip` (transformer): will emit a '`end`' and '`finish`' ([transformer is duplex stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams))
- `out` (writable stream): will finally emit a '`finish`' when all data are written.

Comment: so, I should only be using out.on('finish', function () { .. to do someting when I expect writing has been finished.

Comment: Your second option `zipStream = inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
zipStream.on('finish', function () { .... })` is correct. Because the last pipe, returns the last stream (the writable one).

Comment: there was a typo in first option, can you tell why out.on('finish', function () { .. will not work ?

Comment: Is the same, will work both. Because out === inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out)

Answer (score -1):

```
var inp = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
var out = fs.createWriteStream(fileName + '.gz');
inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
inp.on('finish', function () { ....
```

This is the best since you are listening on the input, plus that's how I used it last.

Comment: have you seen the reference link I have given?