# Waiting for createWriteStream to finish from S3

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-s3

I am downloading a number of items from an Amazon S3 bucket.  I am able to download these, but the code which relies on the items being present fails as the downloads haven't completed by the time the following code runs.  I have the following for my download:

```
  const stream = await download.Body?.pipe(createWriteStream(filePath));
  stream.on('finish', async () => {
    console.log(`${filePath} finished downloading`)
  })
```

and while the file is downloaded, subsequent code runs before the file has been saved.
I did see on here (which I can't find) someone claiming that the finish event doesn't work for S3.

I have also tried

```
await once(stream, 'finish');
```

but that had the same result.  Anyone have any other ideas (or know the event I would need to use?)

Comment: Shouldn't the callback in `stream.on()` method be synchronous since you're already waiting for the finish event to happen ?

Comment: I am not sure - the documents on this are a bit all over

Comment: @johnnyBoy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447872/callback-to-handle-completion-of-pipe was one of the examples I was looking at

Comment: In the accepted solution, the callback is indeed synchronous you don't need to put the `async` keyword. Try this way and let us know

Comment: @johnnyBoy - I did a  stream.on('finish', function(){
    console.log('file downloaded ');
  }); but it still fails to wai\

Comment: I looked up the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-write-stream/) of the  `createWriteStream` method, and it seems the event is `end`, not finish. I don’t know any further, but it’s still weird it doesn’t wait. Can you provide a reproduction in a sandbox ?

Comment: Hi, it gets very much stranger, I was trying to run this within the playwright framework - seems that it works on it's own, but just playwright is doing something odd.