# node.js Writable 'finish' not emitted after pushing null into pipe

Tags: node.js

Here is my minimal example, I would have expected for the writable to emit 'finish' after `readable.push(null);`, but nothing happens.

```js
import { Readable, Writable } from 'stream';

const readable = new Readable();

const writable = new Writable({
    write: (data) => {
        console.log('write', data.toString());
    }
});

writable.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('finish');
});

readable.pipe(writable);

readable.push('test');
readable.push(null);
```

output:

```
write test
```

I also tried `end`, `close` and `complete` on both `writable` and the return value of `.pipe()`, with no results at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the answer that fixed this was removed by the author.

The problem was, that the `callback` parameter of `write` was never called:

```js
import { Readable, Writable } from 'stream';

const readable = new Readable({
    read() {}
});

const writable = new Writable({
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        console.log('write', chunk.toString());
        callback();
    }
});

writable.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('finish');
});

readable.pipe(writable);

readable.push('test');
readable.push(null);
```

output:

```
write test
finish
```